# keeping sourceTree in sync with changing git state?

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

If I have a sourceTree window open, how can I keep it synchronized with changes made via a direct git command?

For example, if I

```
git checkout dev/120
```

or

```
git add foo
```

how can I make sourceTree update its view to match the current repo state?

I'm on a Mac, so applescript incantations would be applicable.

Comment: There is an alternative to Source Tree is GitX, it very simple and fast. If you want to give it a try: https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/

Comment: SourceTree automatically updates if this setting enabled globally or for the repository.

Answer (score 0):

sourcetree seems to "auto-refresh" it's view for me every so often automatically. if it lags behind for some reason i simply do a `Cmd+R` in the repo window in sourcetree and it does a refresh

i am keenly aware of this feature as i sync all my webapp repos to dropbox so i can move from laptop to desktop to home to work. sourcetree tracks my changes pretty much automatically the whole way.